# How can I host flutter web app on Bluehost without having errors?

Tags: flutter, dart, web-applications, host

I'd like to host my web app on my custom host, but it always throws errors - any help please ?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using different Host and I shared to host now not problem. if you want yo see you can check my profile